# Trick Question; Showing 'nr of results' of MySql search

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, database

I have a classifieds website, and users can search ads.

The results are displayed in three tabs on top of the page. These three are "**All**", "**Private**", and "**Company**".
Each tab has a nr attached to it, which represents the nr of ads found in that tab.

So for example:

```
  All     Private     Company
   5         3           2
```

`All` is just a total of private+company!

I am using MySql as a database.

I am trying to figure out a way to find out these "numbers of ads found" for each tab.

I have one way of doing this, which is like this, but gives me a headache because it is so messy:

```
$query = "SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM classified WHERE classified.classified_id=$id";

        if ($adtypes=="Private"){
        $query_priv_comp = "SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM classified WHERE priv_comp='Company'";
        }
        else {
        $query_priv_comp = "SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM classified WHERE priv_comp='Private'";
        }

        switch ($adtypes){ 
            case "Private":
                $query.= " AND classified.priv_comp='Private'";
            break;

            case "Company":
                $query.= " AND classified.priv_comp='Company'";
            break;
        }

        $qry_result = mysql_query($query); // main query
        $result_priv_comp = mysql_query($query_priv_comp); // second query

        $num_priv_comp = mysql_num_rows($result_priv_comp);
        if ($adtypes=="All"){
        $num_total = mysql_num_rows($qry_result);
        }
        else if ($adtypes!="All"){
            $num_total=mysql_num_rows($qry_result) + mysql_num_rows($result_priv_comp);
        }

        if ($adtypes=="Private"){
        $num_private = $num_total - $num_priv_comp;
        $num_company = $num_priv_comp;
        }
        else {
        $num_company = $num_total - $num_priv_comp;
        $num_private = $num_priv_comp;
        }
```

Do you know of any other way which this can be done?

Thanks

**BTW**: I need the rows too, in order to display information to the user of the ads found!

Comment: Please clarify, do you just need the counts, or do you need the individual rows too?

Comment: I need the rows too, in order to display the information also!

Comment: Ok. well have a read up on my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you need exactly. If you just need the counts it's relatively easy:

```
SELECT  count(*)                           count_all
,       sum(if(priv_com = 'Private', 1, 0)) count_private
,       sum(if(priv_com = 'Company', 1, 0)) count_company
FROM    classified
WHERE   classified.classified_id=$id
```

If on the other hand, you need both counts as well as row data, you should either do separate queries for the data and the counts, or use a trick. Let's say your table has an id column wich is primary key, you could do:

```
SELECT  count(*)                           count_all
,       sum(if(priv_com = 'Private', 1, 0)) count_private
,       sum(if(priv_com = 'Company', 1, 0)) count_company
,       classified.*
FROM    classified
WHERE   classified.classified_id=$id
GROUP BY id  -- group by on primary key
WITH ROLLUP
```

The `WITH ROLLUP` magic will give you an extra row with the counts for the entire query. The only snag is that you will receive this row as last row of the entire result, so if you want to report the counts before the data, you're going to have to cache the row data in an php array or so and process that later to build up the page.

Comment: actually what I really need, is the rows for the tab currently displayed. So if the user clicks "private" tab, then only rows from all "private" classifieds is needed and so on. But this is a useful method I think. Thanks

Comment: Camran, ok, gotcha. Well I guess I would probably do separate queries then, one for the count and one for the data. If performance would be an issue, I would probably advise to keep track of the counts in a separate aggregate table.

Comment: Performance is an issue for sure. Could you explain some more about the aggregate table? What is that? Thank you

Comment: COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, and friends are aggregates: condensed values computed over a group of rows. You can calculate aggregates in your SQL query by using the appropriate aggregate function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html). Altertnatively, you can keep track of the individual additions and deletions on your table, and keep a running total in a separate table, the aggregate table. That way you can simply do a single row query to your aggregate table to get the current count. Of course there is extra effort involved in ensuring the agg. table is kep up to date.

Answer (score 1):

After your **switch** variable 
`$query_priv_comp` would be equal to:

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM classified WHERE priv_comp='Company' 
  AND classified.priv_comp='Private'
```

or

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM classified WHERE priv_comp='Private' 
 AND classified.priv_comp='Company'
```

Question: **What the difference???**

Comment: Read before commenting, two different queries

Answer (score 0):

You can select all counts with one query:

```
SELECT priv_comp, COUNT(*) AS record_count FROM classified GROUP BY priv_comp
```

Then you can query all the records needed for the current tab.

These 2 should be separated clearly.